# Regex in C++ to fetch from a regex expression a string in any part of the text

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

Example:

here is the string: `"blablabla123:550:404:487blablabla500:488:474:401blablablabla"`

here is what I'm using:

```
string reg = "(\\d{1,3}):(\\d{1,3}):(\\d{1,3}):(\\d{1,3})";
```

this obviously doesn't work since it is looking for starting with the number, 
and I also want to fetch all results, but I don't know how to do that, even though I looked so much for it. :/

I want to have like 2 arrays with:

> Array 1: should return [1] = "123"; [2] = "550"; [3] = "404"; [4] =
>   "487";
>   Array 2: should return [1] = "500"; [2] = "488"; [3] = "474";
>   [4] = "401";

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

typedef std::tr1::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> str_iterator;
int main () {
    str_iterator res;

string regex = "(\\d{1,3}):(\\d{1,3}):(\\d{1,3}):(\\d{1,3})";
string str = "blablabla123:550:404:487blablabla500:488:474:401blablablabla";
const std::tr1::regex pattern(regex.c_str());
bool valid = std::tr1::regex_match(str, res, pattern);
//res is gonna be an array with the match results
if(valid){
    printf("Matched with size of %d\n", res.size());
    printf("Result 1: %s",res[1]);
    printf("Result 2: %s",res[2]);
    printf("Result 3: %s",res[3]);
    printf("Result 4: %s",res[4]);
}else{
    printf("Not Matched");
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regex_match` will try to match the *entire* string. Obviously in your case, the result will be false (it won't match).

Try to use `regex_search` instead.

Comment: Yea that sound about right,I hope you had explained how could I use regex_search to do that, but since you didn't , it shoud be another topic, so here it goes, I hope you can answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823367/regex-fetching-various-results-with-regex-search

Answer (score -1):

What about this :

```
[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]*
```

It's awful but we'll retrieve 8 numbers separated by any other characters.

```
group(0)    group(1)    group(2)    group(3)    group(4)    group(5)    group(6)    group(7)    
123           550         404         487         500         488           474         401
```

Else you could modify the String replacing every non digit by `:` which would give you:
`:::::::::123:550:404:487:::::::::500:488:474:401::::::::::::`
You just keep non empty values by parsing the String. But that would only work if you're certain not to have empty values